# Add custom form value with product

Tags: product, magento-1.9, custom-options, forms, simple-product

I want to create a form which have some conditional logic.
I tried hard but did not found any free plugin/module to do this.

So finally have a solution that I will create custom form(*That will create by myself not magento's custom option form*) to do that task. But didn't know **How can I add this form values** submitted by user **when he add that product to cart**. And also admin can see the values on the admin panel as well.

I know magento have 'custom option form' associated with product but I m not able to add conditional logic on that form. So How can I submit my form as 'custom option form'.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own fields with your conditional logics and follow this answer:
[Add Text Area to product page for all products](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/31698/add-text-area-to-product-page-for-all-products/31717#31717)

I think this solution is valid for your